# What is class_prior actually?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

I am reading a book about machine learning. In the chapter Naive Bayes, I have encountered a problem:

```
# Create Bernoulli Naive Bayes object with prior probabilities of each class
classifer = BernoulliNB(class_prior=[0.25, 0.5])
```

The target vector has only two classes (Binary Classification).

Why the values of `class_prior` list do not sum up to 1? Two possible classes, two prior probabilities. So this seems a contradiction. Have I forgotten something in statistics? Have I understood `class_prior` in a wrong way?

Comment: That depends on what `BernoulliNB` is exactly.

Comment: It should be equal to 1; It might be a misprint

Comment: The current `sklearn` version (0.24) checks that the priors sum to 1 [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L392); I haven't dug into the revision history to see if it maybe at one time would rescale internally, but more likely it's a misprint.

Comment: D'oh!  Those links are for `GaussianNB`, and a similar check is not done for `BernoulliNB`.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a misprint.  `GaussianNB` checks that the priors sum to 1 [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L392), but the models based on `_BaseDiscreteNB` do not.  See [_update_class_log_prior](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L479) and [fit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L631).

It appears that the models silently accept the priors as-is.  The ultimate output, from `predict_proba`, seems to produce the same output as if you scaled the prior to have unit sum; the joint log-likelihood is uniformly shifted, and I guess the math works out (I haven't checked) so that the actual predictions are the same.  Have a look at [this notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SO66103912_NB_priors.ipynb) if interested.

Comment: Am I asking much if I suggest a simple example with dummy data where this throws indeed an error? :)

Comment: @desertnaut , I was going to say "yes, but I'll do it anyway"; but in trying it, it actually doesn't throw the error.  More digging then, I suppose, unless you already know what's going on...

Comment: Nope, I don't...!